# Coupled first order differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Could someone teach me how to solve Question 1 & 3? I have read over the corresponding chapters in my textbook but I still cannot understand how to solve them. I would like to know the steps on how to solve these questions so that I will be able to re-take the questions (randomised so I want to practice the problems multiple times after I learn how to solve them.)

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Question 1. You have system
$$
\frac{d X}{dt} = X + 5 Y,\\
\frac{d Y}{dt} = 2 X + 3 Y.
$$
Substituting $Y$ from the first equation to the second one, we ge
$$
\frac{d Y}{dt} = 2 X + \frac{3}{5} \frac{d X}{dt} - \frac{3}{5} X = \frac{7}{5} X +  \frac{3}{5} \frac{d X}{dt}.
$$

At the same time, if we differentiate the first equation, then we gen
$$
\frac{d^2 X}{d t^2} = \frac{d X}{dt} + 5 \frac{d Y}{dt}.
$$

Now, we substitute here $\frac{d Y}{dt}$:
$$
\frac{d^2 X}{d t^2} = \frac{d X}{dt} + 7 X + 3\frac{d X}{dt} = 4 \frac{d X}{dt} + 7X.
$$

Hence,
$$
\frac{d^2 X}{d t^2} - 4 \frac{d X}{dt} - 7X = 0,
$$
and so $a = -4$ and $b = -7$.

Question 2. Just substitute the solutions to the differential equations and initial conditions. Then, you will get the standard system of 4 linear equations for 4 unknown coefficients.